# Incompatible versions of libsqlite3-0 (i386 and amd64) block each other

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm trying to install the various i386 libraries required for skype on linux (debian 7.0 wheezy 64-bit), but I've run into a problem where apparently the two versions of libsqlite-3-0 are each blocking the other. Here's the output from aptitude:

```
libsqlite3-0 : Breaks: libsqlite3-0:i386 (!= 3.7.16.2-1~bpo60+1) but 3.7.13-1+deb7u1 is to be installed.
libsqlite3-0:i386 : Breaks: libsqlite3-0 (!= 3.7.13-1+deb7u1) but 3.7.16.2-1~bpo60+1 is installed.
```

I've done a bit of tracking, and here is what I know about those packages:

- libsqlite3-0:i86 is not yet installed.
- libsqlite3-0:amd64 (the normal one) is installed, but instead of the wheezy default of 3.7.13-1, I have a different version from squeeze-backports (from before I upgraded to wheezy): 3.7.16.2-1.
- A google search for libsqlite3-0 3.7.16.2-1 finds several pages about iceweasel. I've tried removing iceweasel, but that's not an option; gnome-core depends on it apparently.

Any ideas for how to resolve this, or investigate further?

---

FYI: derobert's advice got this sorted. The command I needed was this one, to downgrade the libsqlite3-0 (amd64) package:

`aptitude install`*package*`=`*version*

e.g. in this case `aptitude install`*libsqlite3-0*`=`*3.7.13-1+deb7u1*

in full:

```
root@hephaestus:/etc/apt# aptitude install libsqlite3-0=3.7.13-1+deb7u1
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libsqlite3-0 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 455 kB of archives. After unpacking 48.1 kB will be freed.
Get: 1 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.7.13-1+deb7u1 [455 kB]
Fetched 455 kB in 1s (452 kB/s)       
dpkg: warning: downgrading libsqlite3-0:amd64 from 3.7.16.2-1~bpo60+1 to 3.7.13-1+deb7u1
(Reading database ... 179321 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libsqlite3-0:amd64 3.7.16.2-1~bpo60+1 (using .../libsqlite3-0_3.7.13-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libsqlite3-0:amd64 ...
Setting up libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.7.13-1+deb7u1) ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~bpo` in the version number means it comes from [Debian backports](http://backports.debian.org/). If you check [packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libsqlite3-0), you'll see that the version you have installed is from squeeze-backports.

Also, the `:i386` means that it's a 32-bit version.

So it looks like you had Squeeze installed before and also Squeeze backports. And also 32-bit squeeze backports. Or at least, you had that backport installed.

The fix is to upgrade your squeeze backports to Wheezy versions. I suspect that didn't happen automatically because you don't have multi-arch enabled. See https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO and https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch

Comment: Thank you - yes, I did have squeeze installed before, and squeeze backports. I'll look into upgrading those squeeze backport packages.

Comment: Worked completely, cheers.